# Camel RabbitMQ: Messages remain unacknowledged for failed InOut exchange

Tags: apache-camel, rabbitmq

We’re using the rabbitMQ (v3.5.5) InOut feature in camel version 2.16.0 and have set up a flow like the following:

Producer -> route1 -> rabbitMQ -> route2 -> rabbitMQ -> route3 -> service bean

The service bean will return a response which the caller can choose whether or not to be interested in.  It is set up like this so that the routes can be reused for both asynchronous and synchronous processing, where the caller can just indicate whether it cares about a response by setting the exchange pattern to InOnly or InOut.

The rabbitMQ to and from endpoints are configured like the following:

```
from( "direct:route1" )
    .to( "rabbitmq://localhost:5672/testExchange?exchangeType=topic&autoDelete=false&declare=false" );

from( "rabbitmq://localhost:5672/testExchange?queue=queue.test.exchange&exchangeType=topic&autoDelete=false" +
    "&deadLetterExchangeType=direct&deadLetterExchange=deadLetterTestExchange" +
    "&deadLetterQueue=deadletter.test.exchange&deadLetterRoutingKey=#" +
    "&autoAck=false&transferException=true" )
    .throwException( new RuntimeException( "test exception" ) );
```

We have set autoAck=false so that, for an InOnly exchange, if there are any exceptions, the message will be rejected and pushed to a deadletter queue.

However for an InOut exchange, if an exception is thrown, given we have autoAck=false and transferException=true, the original message will remain unacknowledged forever on rabbitMQ, even though the exception is propagated back to the caller to be handled. If the server is restarted, the application will attempt to reprocess the message.

Does anybody know if sending a basicAck or basicReject for the original message would violate any best practices, in the scenario where an InOut exchange fails with transferException=true?

The basicAck/Reject would be done after transferring the exception back to the producer.

For our use case, a basicAck seems more appropriate since the caller is able to handle the exception so there should be no need to also propagate the message to a deadletter queue.

Comment: We submitted a patch to resolve this
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9369